# What techniques do you think duolingo used to make its lesson list in the app?(pic included)

Tags: android

I'm trying to make the duolingo lesson list for fun because im a big fan of the app, im a beginner programmer.

basically id like your opinion on how you think they did it.

here is what it looks like
https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/a3/a8/65/a3a865c47153078e7004b74652af7757.jpg

I think it might be a scroll view and linear layout, then perhaps a class for each icon/progress/name combo that will change based on progress

Comment: your question is not quite clear.

Comment: how about now? i just would mainly like opinions

Answer (score 1):

I think a table layout might be an easier solution.

Check it out here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it, you need to use a scrollView followed by a linearlayout.

Then you can programatically add in relative layouts as rows and in those relative layouts make another square relative layout and in that relative layout you stack up the stuff like image/text/progress